# RMI: are fields of remote object serialized and sent to client?

Tags: java, security, rmi

I have the following code:

```
public class Foo implements SomeRemote {
  private String verySecretString;
  public void doSomething(){...}
}
```

As I understand foo will somehow be serialized and sent from RMI server to RMI client. So, can the client access anyway `verySecretString`?

Comment: Serialization generally doesn't do a deep copy - have you tested to see what gets sent?

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet Serialization *does* do a deep copy, always, but there is no serialization here.

Comment: Interesting, and not the case in other languages, where only the public representations are serialized. I assume there has to be some serialization in order to send that down the wire, but hey, not my language, really.

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet Java Serialization transmits entire object graphs. See the Object Serialization Specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how it works, you are supposed to expose a Remote interface instead of a class then manipulate the interface at client level this way the client has no idea of the implementation details.

So here you should rather have something like:

```
public interface MyService extends Remote {
    void doSomething() throws RemoteException;
}
```

This is only what you know at the client level. At the sever level you will have your implementation `Foo`, something like:

```
public class Foo implements MyService {
    private String verySecretString;
    public void doSomething(){...}
}
```

**Response Update:**

If you don't want a field value to be serialized simply add the keyword `transient` to its declaration as next:

```
private transient String verySecretString;
```

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand foo will somehow be serialized and sent from RMI server to RMI client.

No. If `Foo` is an exported remote object it won't be sent anywhere. Its *stub* will be sent.

> So, can the client access anyway verySecretString?

No.

Comment: Sounds like not a deep copy, then. ;)

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet It is a proxy pattern. Nothing to do with deep or shallow copying, or copying of any kind. And it is done by RMI, not by Serialization.

Comment: Do I understand you right - the client will not have access to instance of `Foo`, client will have access to stub which implements `SomeRemote` interface?

Comment: @Pavel_K I've already answered that. You're just asking me to repeat myself.